# LinkerErrors on opencv3.0 included project

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013

First of all I have already checked many LinkerError questions in stackoverflow. But everything seems connected on my sight. Let me share some information:

Code:

```
#include<opencv\cv.h>
#include<opencv\highgui.h>

void main(){
    IplImage* img = cvLoadImage("C:\kaplan.jpg");
    cvNamedWindow("ImgDisp", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cvShowImage("ImgDisp", img);
    cvWaitKey(0);
    cvReleaseImage(&img);
    cvDestroyWindow("ImgDisp");
}
```

System settings:

- Configuration : Debug
- Platform : x64
- VC++ Directories -> Executable directories =
  C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\bin;$(ExecutablePath)
- VC++ Directories -> Library directories =
  C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\staticlib;C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib;$(LibraryPath)
- C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include directories =
  C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2;C:\opencv\build\include;C:\opencv\build\include\opencv;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)
- Linker -> General -> Additional Library directories =
  C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\staticlib;C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)
- Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies =
  opencv_calib3d300d.lib;opencv_core300d.lib;opencv_features2d300d.lib;opencv_flann300d.lib;opencv_hal300d.lib;opencv_highgui300d.lib;opencv_imgcodecs300d.lib;opencv_imgproc300d.lib;opencv_ml300d.lib;opencv_objdetect300d.lib;opencv_shape300d.lib;opencv_stitching300d.lib;opencv_superres300d.lib;opencv_ts300d.lib;opencv_video300d.lib;opencv_videoio300d.lib;opencv_videostab300d.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)

Error obtained :

> 1>opencv_imgcodecs300d.lib(loadsave.obj) : error LNK2005: "public:
>   __cdecl std::_Container_base12::_Container_base12(void)" (??0_Container_base12@std@@QEAA@XZ) already defined in
>   msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP120D.dll)
>
> 1>opencv_core300d.lib(stat.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external
>   symbol ippicviNormDiff_L2_8s_C3CMR referenced in function "double
>   __cdecl cv::norm(class cv::_InputArray const &,class cv::_InputArray const &,int,class cv::_InputArray const &)"
>   (?norm@cv@@YANAEBV_InputArray@1@0H0@Z)
>
> 1>opencv_core300d.lib(matmul.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external
>   symbol ippicviDotProd_32s64f_C1R referenced in function "double
>   __cdecl cv::dotProd_32s(int const *,int const *,int)" (?dotProd_32s@cv@@YANPEBH0H@Z)
>
> 1>c:\users\juhsis\documents\visual studio
>   2013\Projects\Project1\x64\Debug\Project1.exe : fatal error LNK1120:
>   528 unresolved externals

So, what did I miss?

Comment: Are the opencv libs in the library directories you gave there? Personally I throw .libs in with all of VS's so I don't have to deal with this kind of stuff.

Comment: Yes, I set to opencv libs directory and double checked files. I also copy & paste all libs into VS 2013. Nothing changes. @twentylemon

Comment: please use eithers staticlibs or dynamic ones, not both

Comment: Sidenote: `"C:\kaplan.jpg"` should be `"C:\\kaplan.jpg"`.

Comment: I have already tried with only static libs and only dynamic libs. @berak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just found the source of problem. In opencv 3.0, I realised that all library files I have previously used and located in \lib file has been moved into \staticlib. In \lib file there are only 2 libraries placed: opencv_world300d.lib;opencv_ts300d.lib . Then I erase all links to staticlib folder and all libs under that folder and replaced with \lib folder and libraries under that folder.

Here are the changes in settings I am currently using:

- Configuration : Debug
- Platform : x64
- C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include directories =
  C:\opencv\build\include;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)
- Linker -> General -> Additional Library directories =
  C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)
- Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies =
  opencv_world300d.lib;opencv_ts300d.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)